# Where are the Evolution data files stored?

Tags: evolution

Given that I do use Evolution, and that I have the Ubuntu 12.10, and that I have neither a `~/.evolution` nor a `~/.gconf/.evolution` file, where are the evolution files please?

In particular, every time I try to modify a certain contact evolution crashes, among other problems. Yes, I've reported the bug. So I thought I'd modify the database or xml file directly. Based on a find command, I suppose the evolution files are in

`~/.local/share/evolution/`

Comment: Tip: try to find files based on their modification date: `find -mmin -5 -ls` lists all files modified within the last five minutes.

Answer (score 24):

- The user's data files: `$HOME/.local/share/evolution`
- Various configuration and state files: `$HOME/.config/evolution`
- Disposable data caches: `$HOME/.cache/evolution`
- Additional configuration files: `$HOME/.gconf/apps/evolution`

More details at: [Where does Evolution store my data?](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.10/data-storage.html.en).

Comment: Don't forget: `$HOME/.gconf/apps/evolution` for more config files (those of the several components like addressbook, calendar, mail).

Comment: The link is broken. Current version is at https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.10/data-storage.html.en

Comment: Those data files don't seem to include the calendar entries.