# Evolution messages keeps coming back after uninstall and install

Tags: uninstall, evolution, purge, reinstall

I am unable to perform a fresh installation of Evolution. I tried all the methods given in the post [How do I completely remove Evolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315640/how-do-i-completely-remove-evolution). But it doesn't help.

After I uninstall and reinstall I end up up directly opening the same email which I was reading before uninstall. No setup wizard appears at all.

In short I want to get back the Evolution setup wizard but I do not know how to.

And now evolution seems to hang my computer. And I have to hard reboot.

I just want to get rid of this evolution. I will try thunderbird or clawmail or anything else but never evolution.

I even tried following this guide. [Where are the Evolution data files stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293696/where-are-the-evolution-data-files-stored). But it doesn't help too.

Please help.

Comment: Just delete evolution config file?

Comment: As pointed out by me the post link given by me in the question covers all solution

Comment: @muru please help